# Angular-UI Resolve Promise object inside $urlRouterProvider.when()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set up some basic application data inside the `module.config()` object, and I only do so when the user hits the app with a unique key attached to a specific entry point, otherwise my states will resolve with different responses.

I'm using `$urlRouterProvider.when()`, to catch the user at the specified entry point, then resolve the promise (`$http.get()`), then return the state.  But can't seem to make it work. The data itself *does* return, but the function isn't returning the path, and I can't figure out why.

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/hi/:userkey',function($match,$rootScope, $http){
        $http.get('http://api.com/login/'+$match.userkey)
            .success(function(result){
                $rootScope.data = result;
                  return '/home';
            })

        });
```

I've also tried setting the return value inside `.then()`:

```
.then(function(){
    return '/home';
})
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the return value isn't being processed.

Answer (score 2):

So, I don't feel like this is the best answer, but I've been asked by a few now if I found a solution, and I did get it working by activating the desired state instead of returning it's route.  I don't want to accept this answer however, as I feel esalija's answer *should* work, and I'm trying to put the test together to see if it's actually a bug with `ui.router`.  Until then, this definitely works, and off the top of my head, at least for a small app, it's not costing you much.

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/hi/:userkey',function($match, $http, Api, $state){
        return $http.get('http://api.site.com/index.php/login/'+ $match.userkey).success(function(result){

            Api.userkey = $match.userkey;
            Api.appdata = result;
           
        }).then(function(){
            $state.go('app');
        });
```

You can try it out on my [devsite/#/hi/5300e0ce9dfb8](http://evsvillas.normalgravity.com/#/hi/5300e0ce9dfb8)

#### Edit

I suppose I should feel that dirty doing it this way, it's the same way it's accomplished by the module itself:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when(state.url, ['$match', '$stateParams', function ($match, $stateParams) {
    if ($state.$current.navigable != state || !equalForKeys($match, $stateParams)) {
        $state.transitionTo(state, $match, false);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: instead of "return $http.get", I would suggest instead: $http.get(); return true;

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the promise

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/hi/:userkey', function ($match, $rootScope, $http) {
    return $http.get('http://api.com/login/' + $match.userkey)
        .then(function (result) {
            $rootScope.data = result;
            return '/home';
        });
});
```

Comment: this most definitely does not work.  The moment you nest the return inside the promise, the route will not load, despite a successful call, and execution of any events inside `.then()`

Comment: Confirmed, this does not work. Did you find a resolution for this @BrianVanderbusch?

Comment: @jingman... yes I did! Thanks for the reminder.  Although I'm not sure it's the most acceptable solution.  instead of returning the route, I activated the desired state with `$state.go()`  What do you think? [on github](https://github.com/NormalGravity/evsvillas.com/blob/master/app/src/app.js), [see it in action/#/hi/5300e0ce9dfb8](http://evsvillas.normalgravity.com/#/hi/5300e0ce9dfb8)